# Rails controller params named 'application' in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, controller

I have a Rails controller, and I'm using whitelisted params to create new items:

```
def course_discussion_comment_params
  params.require(:course_discussion_comment).permit!
end
```

Most of the time this works correctly and the logs show me the params hash as

```
Parameters: {"body"=>"xxx", "course_id"=>"xxx", "course_discussion_id"=>"xxx", "course_discussion_comment"=>{"body"=>"xxx"}}
```

However, occasionally the params hash doesn't seem to get parsed correctly by Rails, and the request fails, logging a params hash using `application` instead of `course_discussion_comment`, like below:

```
Parameters: {"body"=>"xxx", "course_id"=>"xxx", "course_discussion_id"=>"xxx", "application"=>{"body"=>"xxx"}}
...
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: course_discussion_comment):
```

I can't seem to find anything causing it on my end, the issue is intermittent and occurs on other controllers too, but it is consistent in that it has happened multiple times, and in particular this controller seems to be affected the worst, happening every few days and only getting resolved when the server is restarted (it's on Heroku, so dyno is restarted daily).

Any ideas of what might be going on? Here is the full controller:

```
class CourseDiscussionCommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_course
  before_action :load_course_discussion
  before_action :set_course_discussion_comment, only: [:update, :destroy]

  before_action {
    in_course(params[:course_id])
  }

  before_action only: [:update, :destroy] {
    current_user(@course_discussion_comment[:from][:_id])
  }

  def create

    course_discussion_comment_params[:from] = {
        _id: @authenticatedUser[:id],
        firstName: @authenticatedUser[:firstName],
        lastName: @authenticatedUser[:lastName],
    }
    course_discussion_comment_params[:deleted] = false
    @course_discussion_comment = @course_discussion.course_topic_comments.build(course_discussion_comment_params)

    if @course_discussion_comment.save
      DiscussionActionMailer.comment_added(request.base_url, @course, @authenticatedUser, @course_discussion, @course_discussion_comment).deliver_now

      render json: @course_discussion_comment, status: 200
    else
      render json: @course_discussion_comment.errors, status: 422
    end
  end

  def update
    if @course_discussion_comment.update(course_discussion_comment_params)
      render json: @course_discussion_comment, status: 200
    else
      render json: @course_discussion_comment.errors, status: 422
    end
  end

  def destroy
    params = {
        :deleted => true
    }

    if @course_discussion_comment.update(params)
      render json: @course_discussion_comment, status: 200
    else
      render json: @course_discussion_comment.errors, status: 422
    end
  end

  private
  def course_discussion_comment_params
    params.require(:course_discussion_comment).permit!
  end

  def load_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  end

  def load_course_discussion
    @course_discussion = @course.course_topics.find(params[:course_discussion_id])
  end

  def set_course_discussion_comment
    @course_discussion_comment = @course_discussion.course_topic_comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant view? Also `[:_id]` this seems dangerous... why are you creating magic variables with underscores in their names... have you considered that variables with underscores are set aside for the use of Rails' internal naming-scopes... which might be where this bug is coming from?

Comment: I am using Mongoid instead of ActiveRecord. `:_id` isn't a magic variable, it is the MongoDB OID generated by Mongoid.

Comment: And the controller is directly rendering the object into JSON, I'm not using a normal View here. The error is occurring before View rendering happens.

Comment: That is not necessarily true... The error is actually occurring at the point where `application` is put into the form that you are submitting to the create action... I think it's occurring in the new action or the new view... (in this instance), rather than the create-action where it's throwing the error.

Comment: Also... `_id` might well be being used by Rails *as well* as mongoid... do you know for certain? How are you so confident? Have you personally gone and checked? (maybe you have, but it's always worth looking at and it definitely stood out to me as "this is not normal, safe operation of rails")